# How to get the value of label text in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the value of a `permission key` in Selenium web-driver(java), but I couldn't able to identify the element. Can anyone please help me to identify the element and get the value `"4BF12-50763-166E0"`.

There are 9 span class with same name and it's quite hard to identify the same.

The web page part look like as below and i want to take each of the below elements value like `version`, `status` etc. All are present in the span class as shown in the below pic.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

```
Version                       1.2
Status                        Enabled
Days left                     373
Permission KEY                4BF12-50763-166E0
Permission Serial Number      99678905096711
Subscription End Date         2020-08-31
```

The sample of the HTML is attached.

I have tried this, but it is selecting `"Permission KEY"` only.

```
  WebElement details =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='Permission KEY']"));
  String title = details.getAttribute("title");
  String label = details.getText();
  System.out.println("Title is  " +title);
  System.out.println("Label is" +label);
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we have what have you tried in terms of code and what is the failure/error that you're getting? Also I see there is an element with id `permission96711`. Is that unique or changes everytime?

Comment: @Linu Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @demouser123  I have edited my question ,but then i realized those are 2 labels and couldn't able to get it by value.Also permission96711 this will change for each run ,So it is not possible that way.Any other way for this please.

Comment: @DebanjanB  I tried to copy the HTML code itself  at the first time,but the alignment and all is varying and make hard to understand for the stackers,so that's why put it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your desired text in this case "Permission Key" go the ancestor element  and go to the second span that contains the value.

XPath:

```
String xpath = "//b[text()='Permission Key']/ancestor::dd/span[2]";
WebElement spanElement =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

spanElement.getText(); // Will give you '4BF12-50763-166E0'
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: You can change the 'Permission Key' to any other value like for example 'Version' and **IF** they follow the same pattern, it will work for all, example:

```
String xpath = "//b[text()='Version']/ancestor::dd/span[2]";
WebElement spanElement =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

spanElement.getText(); // Will give you '1.2'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,I have tried this solution but not able to get an unique element, Attached the screen shot , you can see there are 2 elements while taking with the mentioned method.Any suggestions please.

Comment: Alright, but what you want? The first element or the second? If your screen have more than one record, you need to choose which one, are you searching for any SPEFIC value that you know before you search on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preceding-sibling` strategy in your `xpath`, try this bellow :

```
WebElement key = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='pull-right property-value' and ./preceding-sibling::span/b[contains(text(),'Permission KEY')]]"));
System.out.println("Permission KEY : " +key.getText());
```

Make sure this is the correct class name : `@class='pull-right property-value'`, because i see from your image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,I have tried this solution but not able to get an unique element, Attached the screen shot , you can see there are 2 elements while taking with the mentioned method.Any suggestions please.

Comment: try `(//b[text()='Version']/ancestor::dd/span[2])[1]` and try change `[1]` to `[2]`